# Why is the bulk of the kernel image only ~1.5MB in RAM after loaded?

Tags: linux, kernel

According to this picture from [The Kernel Boot Process](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/kernel-boot-process):
[image: RAM contents after boot loader is done]

The bulk of the kernel image is only ~1.5MB. I thought the kernel image should be a fairy large binary image file in order to support the hardware (or is this kernel module?) and various kernel functions, since the source is pretty large. Also, where's the `initrd`?

Comment: Hmm I thought that the kernel would be at least ~100MB in RAM, not counting the `initrd`. Or, passed the kernel image is memory region of applications, include `initrd`?

Comment: @Amumu why would it be so big? Linux runs fine on systems with as little as 16MB RAM or even less.

Comment: As an example, `vmlinuz` (the compressed kernel image) is about 2Mb in size on my Debian 6 x86 system, which is similar to what is on that picture. The size, of course, may vary among different distros and kernel configurations. After the kernel is uncompressed, it may take much more memory.

Comment: And also, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadable_kernel_module#Linux

Comment: They try to keep the size of the running kernel as small as possible, because that's RAM that you don't get to use for what the computer is actually *for*.

Comment: @Zack Thanks, although I understood this after practicing. `vmlinuz` is for the essential kernel content (with built-in drivers), while `initrd` is for loadable kernel modules (i.e. non-essential drivers) which can't be built in. `initrd` will be discarded shortly after the kernel complete booting.

Answer (score 1):

First the kernel is compressed. Then in most desktop environment, the kernel is built with a minimal set of statically linked modules. The initrd image is loaded from the hard drive, from the /boot folder (see your grub configuration) and is used to detect your desktop hardware to load the appropriate modules, to be able to mount a root file system. The initrd image contains this sets of modules. Imagine a RAID, LVM or an exotic file system that cannot be recognized by the bootloader. This is why the boot partition is most of time in ext2/3/(4?). Then when the right modules are loaded, the root file system is swapped from initrd image with the one on the hard drive (pivot_root). Then the rest of the hardware modules are loaded from the "none initrd" filesystem, mostly with the help of udev.

Hope this helps!

**P.S.** Correct me if I'm wrong!